# Error accessing pandas row element named class

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an invalid syntax error when I try obtain the class element in each row:

```
for rows in testData.itertuples():
    c = classify(rows.subj_text, priors, cpParams)
    currC = rows.class
```

I believe the error might due to the fact that class is a reserved word? How could I fix the issue.

Comment: Well can you easily rename the field? Make your life easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used `iterrows` instead of `itertuples`, you could use getitem-style access instead of attribute access.  For example:

```
In [33]: testData = pd.DataFrame({"subj_text": ["a","b"], "class": [10,20]})

In [34]: for _, row in testData.iterrows():
    ...:     print(row["subj_text"], row["class"])
    ...:     
a 10
b 20
```

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `class` is a problem.  You can access the field in the tuple as:

```
currC = rows[list(testData.columns).index('class') + testData.index.nlevels]
```